# Incrementing pointer in function argument

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

I have the following code:

```
int x;
int * xPtr = &x;

int * Get_xPtr(void);
void someFunction(int * y);

int * Get_xPtr(void)
{
    return xPtr;
}

void someFunction(int * y)
{
    ...
    ...
}

void main(void)
{
    someFunction(++Get_xPtr());
}
```

This code is compiling fine without the increment on the return value (address) of function Get_xPtr(), but with the increment I get the error:

"error: lvalue required as increment operand"

I guess this is not allowed syntax, but why? Is there any other way to do this or do I need to:

```
int * tempPtr = GetxPtr();
tempPtr++;
someFunction(tempPtr);
```

Comment: `someFunction(Get_xPtr() + 1)`

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right, that worked. Why doesn't the compiler interpret ++ and +1 similar?

Comment: Because you can't write to a temp expression.

Comment: @user1840438: Because the return value of the function is a temporary object ("not an lvalue"), so the increment operator is not allowed there -- its purpose is to change the state of an object, but if the object is temporary, this usually makes no sense and hence isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someFunction(++Get_xPtr());
```

`++Get_xptr()` requires lvalue to store return value.

simple example will make some clarification

```
int i=0;
++i; ==>i=i+1; //result stored in i.
```

variable i can change

```
++5; //where is lvalue ?
```

You can use

```
someFunction(Get_xPtr()+1);
```